# XNA ModelMesh.Draw vs GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives

Tags: xna, 3d, models

I am using XNA 4.0 and I wonder if drawing models with multiple meshes is better by filling the vertex and index buffers first and calling GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives() or by simply using good ol' foreach(...) {ModelMesh.Draw()}.

Is it possible to add data to vertex/index buffers at all in order to pack all the models on the scene in them and then call Draw only once per frame?

I would appreciate a link to an in-depth explanation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is called "instancing" or "batching". It is indeed faster to pile geometry before calling "Draw". An example with source code can be found here:

http://jcoluna.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/xna-light-pre-pass-instancing/